# how to make a loop on a json file?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have to handle a JSON file.

In JSON BLOCAGES -> BLOCAGE > I have to retrieve `QTE` and `DTE`.

Here is my file JSON [here](http://jsonblob.com/894529891031334912)

My problem is that, I display `QTE` and `DTE` one time.

For now, I have this => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kEjF2.png)

I want to get this result => [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dx1F9.png)

I'm missing the array elements `[1]` and `[2]`, how could I add them from a loop?

Here is my method **prepareDataForBlocage()**

```
prepareDataForBlocage(response) {
    this.spinners.blockDetails = false;
    if (response['RETURNCODE'] == "OKK00") {


        let [variable1] = response['BLOCAGES']['BLOCAGE'];

        this.statusLine = {
            quantity: variable1['QTE'],
            update: variable1['DAT'],

        };

    }
}
```

My HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped">
   <tr style="background-color: #f8f9fa; font-weight: bold;">
      <td style="width: 13%;">Quantity</td>
      <td style="width: 13%;">Reason</td>
      <td style="width: 13%;">Date</td>
      <td style="width: 13%;">Référence</td>
   </tr>
   <tr  *ngIf="statusLine.quantity != 0" >
      <td>
         {{statusLine.quantity | number:'1.2-2' }}
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         {{statusLine.update | dateddmmyyyy }}
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Use an array of lines, not a single destructured element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems in your code

the first:

```
let [variable1] = response['BLOCAGES']['BLOCAGE'];
/// is the same as
let variable1 = response['BLOCAGES']['BLOCAGE'][0];
/// That means you only get the first element of your list
```

the second is that you do not loop over an array in your template.

You could try something like:

```js
 this.myList = response['BLOCAGES']['BLOCAGE']
  .filter(blocage => blocage['QTE'] != 0)
  .map(blocage => ({
    quantity: blocage['QTE'],
    update: blocage['DAT'],
  }));
```

```html
 <tr *ngFor="let elem of myList" >
      <td>
         {{elem.quantity | number:'1.2-2'  }}
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
         {{elem.update | dateddmmyyyy  }}
      </td>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have an error of syntax on `});` ?

Comment: I've forgot a parenthesis => `}));`